# Multi-dimensional lists control in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If [i][0] is the same value on the list, I am trying to leave only one value of [i][0] and then add each value of [i][1].

Here is a sample code below.

```
[['R21', 120], ['R21', 120], ['R23', 200]]
```

Here is the result I look forward to.

```
[['R21',240],['R23',200]]
```

I created a single list of each, find duplicate values, add the index of those values.
Is there a way to implement it without creating a single list?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do this by walking through your list once would be the following:

```
x = [['R21', 120], ['R21', 120], ['R23', 200]]
result = {}
for pair in x:
    key, value = pair
    if key in result:
        result[key] += value
    else:
        result[key] = value
# result is {'R21': 240, 'R23': 200}
```

Now, if you insist upon a list of lists, we can write:

```
result = [list(item) for item in result.items()]
```

However, `result.items()` will give you a list of `tuples`, so it is not necessary to convert to this list of lists unless you intend to expand or modify them. This second step adds a second walk through of your initial list.

Comment: @purelyawwesome No problem! Glad to help

Answer (score 3):

You can create temporary dictionary to hold your values and then convert back to list of lists:

```py
lst = [["R21", 120], ["R21", 120], ["R23", 200]]

out = {}
for k, v in lst:
    out.setdefault(k, 0)
    out[k] += v

out = [[k, v] for k, v in out.items()]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[['R21', 240], ['R23', 200]]
```

Comment: Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best solution time and space wise but it is scalable for any input and clear for anyone to understand; I did not want to use python list comprehension to make it clearer:

```
numbers = [['R21', 120], ['R21', 120], ['R23', 200]]

def merge(nums):
    new = []
    checked = []

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i][0] in checked:
            continue
        target = nums[i]
        sm = target[1]
        for n in nums[i+1:]:
            if n[0] == target[0]:
                sm += n[1]
        new.append([target[0], sum])
        checked.append(target[0])

    return new

print(merge(numbers))
```

Output:

```
[['R21', 240], ['R23', 200]]
```